# Mercedes M1 broken into but no physical damage. Multiple times

Tags: mercedes-benz, theft-prevention

My Mercedes M1 (2012) was broken into last night, however they did not steal the car, and there was no physical damage to the doors or the window frame. All of the windows where up and the car was definitely locked.

This is the second time this has happened: I have woken up in the morning to find my car with the doors open and all of the interior compartments opened and searched.

Does anyone know how they would have done this, and of so what modifications / precautions I can take to prevent it from happening again?

Thanks for any help.

(I know this is not the normal type of question asked and is slightly off topic, however I hope that the mechanism I've in here may have seen / heard about this)

Comment: Someone somehow has a duplicate key... Most probably they were locking their car one day and yours reacted as well. I had this with a car - another parent had the same model of car and we opened it and started to get in... Had a good laugh with the real owner eventually... :)

Comment: I guess that is possible, however I expected better from a high end (ish) car

Comment: Well mine was VW...

Comment: The issue is, they did not steal the car (which a key is needed for to start it). I was thinking they may have found a way to just unlock it

Comment: Door locks are not always the same as the locks used on the steering lock.

Comment: Yes, that works. So they just have the key by chance? Or do they have a tool that just let's them unlock any Mercedes? (Audi TT and Lexus CT200H not broken into despite being on same drive)